# Powershell Scheduled return code 2147942401

Tags: powershell

I create a task Schedule by below code in powershell,

```
#Variables
$TaskName = "Audit Large Lists"
$username ="Crescent\SP13_FarmAdmin"
$password ="Password Here"
#Create Scheduled Task
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "E:\Scripts\Cleanup.ps1"
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 1am
$ScheduledTask = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $Tas
```

when task run return this massage as task completed:

Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\CleanUp" , instance "{0e729095-760d-93zx-b51f-7fd15b49d555}" , action "PowerShell.exe" with return code 2147942401.

but the powershell code do not run.

I try "Run as Previl..." and many sloution to solve it but it not work.

Comment: In hex that's 0x80070001.

Comment: What happens when you run E:\Scripts\Cleanup.ps1 manually in the shell?

Comment: Where in your code do you actually use `$username` and `password` ? Why do you register the scheduled task with an undefined taskname `$Tas` ?